# css pause slideshow on hover

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to make it so when I hover my mouse over the slideshow, it will pause the animation.

Secondly, I'm trying to make the Pause/Resume buttons work to have the same effect.

I'm struggling on this. Any help would be appreciated. [This is what I have so far](http://codepen.io/ronako/pen/yNoYMm):

```css
body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.css-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 5em auto .5em auto;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure {
  /*transition: opacity .5s;*/
  /*opacity: 1;*/
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.css-slideshow img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 370px;
  color: #000;
  /*background: rgba(0,0,0, .3);*/
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  opacity: 1;
  /*transition: opacity .5s;*/
}
.pauseplay {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5em auto .5em auto;
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption {
  /*transition: opacity .5s;*/
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused !important;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused !important;
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
.css-slideshow-attr {
  max-width: 495px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.css-slideshow-attr a {
  color: #666;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  opacity: 0;
}
figure:nth-child(1) {
  animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(5) {
  animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(6) {
  animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(7) {
  animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(8) {
  animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.css-slideshow.paused figure {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused !important;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused !important;
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
.css-slideshow.playing figure {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running !important;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running !important;
  -o-animation-play-state: running !important;
  animation-play-state: running !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slideshow">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-css3.jpg" alt="class-header-css3" width="495" height="370" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-172" />
    <figcaption><strong>CSS3:</strong> CSS3 delivers a wide range of stylization and effects, enhancing the web app without sacrificing your semantic structure or performance. Additionally Web Open Font Format (WOFF) provides typographic flexibility and control far
      beyond anything the web has offered before.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-semantics.jpg" alt="class-header-semantics" width="495" height="370" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-179" />
    <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to structure, semantics are front and center with HTML5. A richer set of tags, along with RDFa, microdata, and microformats, are enabling a more useful, data driven web for both programs and your users.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-offline.jpg" alt="class-header-offline" width="495" height="370" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-178" />
    <figcaption><strong>Offline &amp; Storage:</strong> Web Apps can start faster and work even if there is no internet connection, thanks to the HTML5 App Cache, as well as the Local Storage, Indexed DB, and the File API specifications.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-device.jpg" alt="class-header-device" width="495" height="370" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-177" />
    <figcaption><strong>Device Access:</strong> Beginning with the Geolocation API, Web Applications can present rich, device-aware features and experiences. Incredible device access innovations are being developed and implemented, from audio/video input access to
      microphones and cameras, to local data such as contacts &amp; events, and even tilt orientation.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-connectivity.jpg" alt="class-header-connectivity" width="495" height="370" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-176" />
    <figcaption><strong>Connectivity:</strong> More efficient connectivity means more real-time chats, faster games, and better communication. Web Sockets and Server-Sent Events are pushing (pun intended) data between client and server more efficiently than ever before.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-multimedia.jpg" alt="class-header-multimedia" width="495" height="370" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-175" />
    <figcaption><strong>Multimedia:</strong> Audio and video are first class citizens in the HTML5 web, living in harmony with your apps and sites. Lights, camera, action!</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-3d.jpg" alt="class-header-3d" width="495" height="370" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-174" />
    <figcaption><strong>3D, Graphics &amp; Effects:</strong> Between SVG, Canvas, WebGL, and CSS3 3D features, you're sure to amaze your users with stunning visuals natively rendered in the browser.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-performance.jpg" alt="class-header-performance" width="495" height="370" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-173" />
    <figcaption><strong>Performance &amp; Integration:</strong> Make your Web Apps and dynamic web content faster with a variety of techniques and technologies such as Web Workers and XMLHttpRequest 2. No user should ever wait on your watch.</figcaption>
  </figure>

</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<center>
  <div id="css-slideshow">

    <button onclick="runSlide();">Resume</button>
    <button onclick="stopSlide();">Pause</button>

  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Please put all the relevant code in the question itself and not just link to it and ask only one question in per post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

For pausing the slideshow on hover, you have to set animation-play-state: pause on the figure and not on the figurecaption on line 36, like so:

```
.css-slideshow:hover figure{
  /*transition: opacity .5s;*/
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; 
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused; 
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

(you also don't need all those .figure:hover declarations and not even the !important)

for the buttons to work you can write some Javascript to add a class on click, with a different animation-play-state value. I see you're calling those runSlide and stopSlide functions but these are not defined anywhere in the JS.
There are different ways to do it depending on your preferences, etc. A simple code that achieves what you want and goes along what you write could be something like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('css-slideshow');

function runSlide(){
  var btnClass = btn.className;
  btn.className = btnClass.concat(" playing");
}

function stopSlide(){
  var btnClass = btn.className;
  btn.className = btnClass.concat(" paused");
}
```

in this case don't forget to add a `id="css-slideshow"` to the div container, extend the selector above with `.css-slideshow.paused figure` and create a `.css-slideshow.playing figure` with `animation-play-state: running`

Comment: Thanks....what am I missing in getting the buttons to work?  I added the javascript code and added the id="css-slideshow' to the div container for the buttons.

Comment: you need to add the paused selector to the declaration at the top, having like .css-slideshow:hover figure, .css-slideshow.paused figure { ... and also the playing selector for when you click Resume, like .css-slideshow.playing figure {  animation-play-state: running; ...

Comment: of course if you want to cleanup and optimize you can use the inputs solution, but if you have to support IE8 you would need a polyfill for that :checked selector

Comment: So the slideshow is working.  The final thing is why nothing shows in a mobile phone browser?

Comment: you don't see anything at all? do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"` in the head section for optimizing the view on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

## Pause and play CSS animation — pure CSS

Note: Only the [`-webkit-` prefix is required currently.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) All relevant, non-webkit browsers support the standard animation property.

### The pause CSS

The animation is paused when the checkbox is checked or `.slideshow` is hovered:

```
.css-slideshow:hover figure,
#pauseShow:checked ~ figure {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

All the figures are selected with the sibling selector (`~`) which will select any `figure` sibling that is after the checkbox input.

### The buttons

The animation is paused when a checkbox is checked. The checkbox itself is hidden, the HTML looks like this and is placed *before* all the `<figure>` elements:

```
<input id="pauseShow" type="checkbox">
<label class="pause" for="pauseShow">Pause</label>
<label class="play" for="pauseShow">Play</label>
```

and the CSS for the labels looks like this:

```
#pauseShow:checked + label,
#pauseShow:not(:checked) + label + label {
  display: none;
}
```

- When the checkbox is checked (The animation is pause), the "Pause" label is hidden.
- When the checkbox is not checked (The animation is playing), the "Play" label is hidden.

### Complete example

```css
body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.css-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 5em auto .5em auto;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.css-slideshow img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 370px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.pauseplay {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5em auto .5em auto;
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.css-slideshow-attr {
  max-width: 495px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.css-slideshow-attr a {
  color: #666;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  opacity: 0;
}
figure:nth-child(1) {
  animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(5) {
  animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(6) {
  animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(7) {
  animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(8) {
  animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure,
#pauseShow:checked ~ figure {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.css-slideshow label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -150px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background: #EEE;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input#pauseShow {
  display: none;
}
#pauseShow:checked + label,
#pauseShow:not(:checked) + label + label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slideshow">
  <input id="pauseShow" type="checkbox">
  <label class="pause" for="pauseShow">Pause</label>
  <label class="play" for="pauseShow">Play</label>

  <figure>
    <img alt="class-header-css3" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-172" height="370" src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-css3.jpg" width="495">

    <figcaption>
      <strong>CSS3:</strong> CSS3 delivers a wide range of stylization and effects, enhancing the web app without sacrificing your semantic structure or performance. Additionally Web Open Font Format (WOFF) provides typographic flexibility and control
      far beyond anything the web has offered before.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img alt="class-header-semantics" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-179" height="370" src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-semantics.jpg" width="495">

    <figcaption>
      <strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to structure, semantics are front and center with HTML5. A richer set of tags, along with RDFa, microdata, and microformats, are enabling a more useful, data driven web for both programs and your users.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img alt="class-header-offline" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-178" height="370" src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-offline.jpg" width="495">

    <figcaption>
      <strong>Offline &amp; Storage:</strong> Web Apps can start faster and work even if there is no internet connection, thanks to the HTML5 App Cache, as well as the Local Storage, Indexed DB, and the File API specifications.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img alt="class-header-device" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-177" height="370" src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-device.jpg" width="495">

    <figcaption>
      <strong>Device Access:</strong> Beginning with the Geolocation API, Web Applications can present rich, device-aware features and experiences. Incredible device access innovations are being developed and implemented, from audio/video input access
      to microphones and cameras, to local data such as contacts &amp; events, and even tilt orientation.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img alt="class-header-connectivity" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-176" height="370" src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-connectivity.jpg" width="495">

    <figcaption>
      <strong>Connectivity:</strong> More efficient connectivity means more real-time chats, faster games, and better communication. Web Sockets and Server-Sent Events are pushing (pun intended) data between client and server more efficiently than ever
      before.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img alt="class-header-multimedia" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-175" height="370" src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-multimedia.jpg" width="495">

    <figcaption>
      <strong>Multimedia:</strong> Audio and video are first class citizens in the HTML5 web, living in harmony with your apps and sites. Lights, camera, action!
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img alt="class-header-3d" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-174" height="370" src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-3d.jpg" width="495">

    <figcaption>
      <strong>3D, Graphics &amp; Effects:</strong> Between SVG, Canvas, WebGL, and CSS3 3D features, you're sure to amaze your users with stunning visuals natively rendered in the browser.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img alt="class-header-performance" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-173" height="370" src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/class-header-performance.jpg" width="495">

    <figcaption>
      <strong>Performance &amp; Integration:</strong> Make your Web Apps and dynamic web content faster with a variety of techniques and technologies such as Web Workers and XMLHttpRequest 2. No user should ever wait on your watch.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```